# NULL if statement excecuted wrong in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Node.js, I've made a function that looks like this:

```
function makeTitleWith(name) {
   if (name === null) {
         return "Hello, welcome to my app!"
   } else {
         return "Hello, welcome " + name + "!"
   }
}
```

And when I call it with a variable thats null, it returns `"Hello, welcome null!"`. I'm new pretty new to JS, and this is driving me insane. I've also tried `==` instead of `===` but it makes no difference.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, it executes the other block. Not the === null one. I fixed my question now.

Comment: Then please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem.

Comment: @andymccullough Yes I have also tried checking for undefined, but it didnt change anything. And if the value im passing to the function would be undefined, it would log to the console as undefined instead of null right?

Comment: Can you please post here what the console.log(name) returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I call it with a variable thats null, it returns "Hello, welcome null!"

That means you're **not** calling it with `name` set to `null`, you're calling it with `name` set to `"null"` (or an unlikely second possibility I'll cover later). `"null"` is not equal to `null` (either `==` or `===`).

Example:

```js
function makeTitleWith(name) {
   if (name === null) {
         return "Hello, welcome to my app!"
   } else {
         return "Hello, welcome " + name + "!"
   }
}
console.log(makeTitleWith("null"));
// or more likely:
var n = String(null);
console.log(makeTitleWith(n));
```

You probably want to fix where you're calling it, since that `"null"` is probably the result of converting `null` to string.

---

The unlikely second possibility: You're calling it with `name` set to an object that, when converted to string, converts to `"null"`, like this:

```js
function makeTitleWith(name) {
   if (name === null) {
         return "Hello, welcome to my app!"
   } else {
         return "Hello, welcome " + name + "!"
   }
}

var n = {
    toString() {
        return "null";
    }
};
console.log(makeTitleWith(n));
```

I very much doubt that's what's going on.

Comment: `"Hello, welcome " + name + "!"` will coerce `null` into a string anyway.

Comment: @BenM - It *would*, but it won't given the OP's code, which checks for `null` and takes another branch.

Comment: This was the case, what would be the best way to prevent this from happening? Should i write my own toString function, which checks for the value being null and preventing it from being changed to string (and causing a disaster in my code), or is there some existing way that everyone uses?

Comment: @user109321948492842303 - Do the `null` check before converting to string, e.g. `x = y === null ? null : String(y);` or similar. You could make your own `toNonNullString` function or similar, but if you're doing your validation early, it isn't really needed.

Comment: As an aside, you can catch null, undefined, empty string, and false with: ```if(name)```

Comment: @DovRine - Don't forget `NaN` and `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you can modify the above code like this (more like defensive coding) and expect/enforce the caller to send the string value as input param to the function.

```
if(typeof name == "string"){
    return "Hello, welcome " + name + "!";
}
return "Hello, welcome to my app!";
```

Also note, if the caller is calling the function with null or empty object, in both the cases, typeof operator returns object. So based on your case I don't think that the method was called with null or empty object.